# Insert Text Fields into a Database with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to add text to a database with a text entry, heres the part of the text entry of index.php:

```
<form action="steamauth/senddb.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="John Doe">
<input type="text" name="steamid" placeholder="12939124953">
<input type="text" name="server" placeholder="VanityRP | DarkRP"><br><br>
<input type="submit" class='btn btn-success' style='margin: 2px 3px;'>
</form>
```

Now heres the steamauth/senddb.php code:

```
 $value1 = $_POST['username'];
$value2 = $_POST['steamid'];
$value3 = $_POST['server'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO StaffTeam (username, steamid, server) VALUES('".$value1."', '".$value2."', '".$value3."')"; 
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Admin added succesfully, redirecting in 3 seconds...";
header( "refresh:3;url=http://vanityrp.site.nfoservers.com/index.php" );
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

So, now, the problem is, im getting empty records on the database, how can i fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong here.

First, you're using a GET method in your form, but then using POST arrays.

- Both need to match. POST/POST and not GET/POST.

Then you're outputting before header with echo on top of headers.

- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

If you are trying to pass data that MySQL will complain about, such as `John's Bar & Grill` (apostrophes), then you will need to escape your data; something you should be doing anyway.

I.e.:

```
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['var']);
```

Your column types and lengths should also be correct and able to accomodate the data.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Plus, make sure you are successfully connected to your database with `mysqli_`.

- Different MySQL APIs do not intermix. (sidenote).